# ¿como creo una columna con el nombre de los idiomas, a partir de una columna con diccionarios con los idiomas?, usando Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diccionarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un DataFrame con ese formato, hay muchos más valores, quisiera crear una tercer columna llamada idioma, donde estén los nombres de los idiomas("name", de los diccionarios).

Probé esto:

```
lenguajes_hablados["idioma"] = lenguajes_hablados["spoken_languages"].get("name")
lenguajes_hablados["idioma"] = lenguajes_hablados["spoken_languages"]["name"]
```

pero no me funciona y supongo que es porque se le esta aplicando el get y el ["name"] a la Serie y no al valor que contiene esa celda. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya se me ocurrio:

```
lenguajes_hablados["idioma"] = lenguajes_hablados["spoken_languages"].map(lambda x: x["name"])
```

Comment: No olvides explicar tu respuesta en base a [answer], y de [aceptarla](/help-accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.